# VS2010 Performance

Tags: windows, performance, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

so i have this laptop Compaq Presario C700
intel T2310 + 2.5GB RAM + 120GB HDD + intel GMA 965
im running Windows 7 ultimate + VS2008
VS2008 is fast but VS2010 is sluggish and laggy idk why
i searched a bit and i found that i could get better performance on XP than Win7
is that true ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit faster on XP due to a lower base memory requirement. But instead of grading down you should consider grading up: your RAM.

Comment: isn't 2.5GB enough ?
BTW when i check ram usage i find only 40%

Comment: In general, I would recommend you upgrading your RAM. Open a browser while developing, having the email client running and so on consume your RAM.

Comment: i think i have enough RAM for now;
the problem is not related to RAM usage

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the graphics settings that VS2010 uses by default (the move to WPF also meant leveraging more intense graphics).  You can turn the graphics settings down in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General, under the Visual Experience section.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in a Win7-64bit machine and it is about 10 times slower than VS2005, even turning visual experience down...

Probably the only way to speed it up is to disable intellisense or parts of it. Try looking at the options...